# How to get the title and post summarization ？

Tags: php, wordpress

Supposted the url of installed wordpress is `example.com/blog`. now i want to get the latest five titles of my blog in a file named test.php. the `test.php` url is:`example.com/test.php`.if i want to get the random of five posts titles and the summarization which under the specified category. how do i do?

Comment: OK. As far as I understand, there is a script "Test.php" with 5 posts and you want to publish them one by one in single pages and also in the summary page for the category they belong to. If I am right, please confirm.

Comment: Use this reference http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query. You can set your query to fetch title and excerpt of 5 random post in specific category.

Comment: Felipe Alameda A ,you are right.Test.php there are two block to show the contetent,

Comment: but test.php not in blog file,how do i use WP_Query?

Comment: @stack01: You can't, unless it is a post already in the database. Follow **AMYunus** suggestion, it will help you to figure out what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make test.php a Template Page and assign your Blog page with this template.

Use this as a reference http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates